# Javascript creating table and returning an undefined value

Tags: javascript, html, undefined

I am creating a table from an array. It was working perfectly until I added a new column which adds a number to the return results. The app asks the user for a number between 1 to 10. Based on the number it randomly picks the values and displays them in a table. I wanted it to be returned as 1 - UNO, 2 - Monopoly and etc. I added the random function and the create table function so you can see the big picture. Currently when I enter in 2 it gives me 1. UNO, 2 - undefined.

```
/* Function that chooses the random game and adds it to the gamesPicked array */
function createRandomArray() {

  var numOfGamesElement = document.getElementById("numOfGames");
  var numOfGames = numOfGamesElement.value;

/* ARRAYS */
  const boardGames = ["UNO", "Monopoly", "Clue", "Pandemic", "Catan", "Articulate!", "Codenames", "Fallout", "Candy Land", "Scrabble"];

  var gamesPicked = [];

/* FOR LOOP */
  for(let i = 0; i < numOfGames; i++){
/* Identify which game is chosen based off location within array */
    gameID = Math.floor(Math.random() * boardGames.length); 
    gameName = boardGames[gameID];
/* Add game to gamesPicked array */
    gamesPicked[i] = gameName;
    createTable(gamesPicked);
  }
}
```

Create Table Function

```
/* Function that creates the table */
function createTable(gamesPicked) {

/* Get the table element from the HTML file */
  var tbl = document.getElementById("data");
  tbl.innerHTML = "";

/* Create the table headers & row & cells */
  var row = tbl.insertRow(0);
  var num = row.insertCell(0);
  var game = row.insertCell(1);

  num.innerHTML = "Number";
  game.innerHTML = "Game";

/* Add game names to cells */
  for(var i = 1; i <= gamesPicked.length; i++){
    
    var row = tbl.insertRow(-1);
    var num = row.insertCell(0);
    var game = row.insertCell(1);
    
    num.innerHTML = i;
    game.innerHTML = gamesPicked[i];
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling createTable inside of the for loop?

Comment: `var i = 1; i <= gamesPicked.length` off by one error when you reference `gamesPicked[i];` <-- i is one more than the actual length, you skip index zero

Comment: That is interesting and good point. So how do I get my numbering to start at 1 and not omit my 0 index within the array?

Comment: `for(var i = 0; i < gamesPicked.length; i++)` then `num.innerHTML = i+1`

Comment: That did it!! Thank you @steve